# In python, how can I can I code this sense: "when true for all members of the list, do this."

Tags: python

I am trying to write a very simple program. I would take a list of numbers, and would check whether all the members of the list is evenly divided by a given integer. Here is the present situation of my code:

```
def evenlist(lst,y):
   print lst
   for i in range(len(lst)):
       print int(lst[i]) % y == 0
x = '2,5,6,8,10'
lst = x.split(',')
y = 2
if evenlist (lst,y):  #(?????)
# Here is the problem....
    print 'All are evenly divided by', y
else:
    print 'All are not evenly divided by', y
```

How can I say, if all of evenlist (lst,y) is true, print this.

---

Update:

Now my code is solved. Corrected code:

```
def evenlist(lst,y):
print lst
result = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
   result.append(int(lst[i]) % y == 0)
return result   
x = '2,4,6,8,10'
lst = x.split(',')
y = 2
if all (evenlist(lst,y)):
    print 'All are evenly divided by', y
else:
    print 'All are not evenly divided by', y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, your `evenlist` function does not return anything. It just prints whether all the numbers are even or not and then implicitly returns `None`, which is interpreted as `False` in the condition.

To test all the members in the list, use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) builtin function and return it's result:

```
def evenlist(lst,y):
    return all(int(x) % y == 0 for x in lst)
```

What this does: It generates a new list, in which each element is the result of the condition (`True` or `False`), and then tests whether all the values in that list are `True` (or otherwise "truthy"):

```
>>> lst = [2, 5, 6, 8, 10]
>>> [x % 2 == 0 for x in lst]
[True, False, True, True, True]
>>> all(x % 2 == 0 for x in lst)
False
```

Example:

```
>>> evenlist("2,5,6,8,10".split(','), 2)
False
>>> evenlist("2,12,6,8,10".split(','), 2)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on the path that you are on, you can turn `evenlist()` into a generator and then iterate through it with `all()`:

```
def evenlist(lst,y):
   print lst
   for i in range(len(lst)):
       yield int(lst[i]) % y == 0

x = '2,5,6,8,10'
lst = x.split(',')
y = 2

if all(x for x in evenlist(lst,y)):
    print 'All are evenly divided by', y
else:
    print 'All are not evenly divided by', y
```

Comment: I don't know much about 'yield' command. If I use 'return' instead of 'yield', the code doesn't work. Can you please explain this yield feature.

Comment: `yield` turns the function into a generator, it's essentially an object that you can iterate through.  `all()` then goes through the generator, which one by one yields true or false for each element of the list you pass to it.

Comment: Also see [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/1639625)

Answer (score 1):

hi you should check if they are even in def

```
def evenlist(lst,y):
 # print lst
x = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
   x += int(lst[i]) % y
if x==0:
    return True
else:
    return False

x = '2,4,6,8,10'
lst = x.split(',')
y = 2
if evenlist (lst,y):
 print 'All are evenly divided by', y
else:
 print 'All are not evenly divided by', y
```

Comment: Your approach is also a clever one. :)

Comment: `return x == 0` is simpler. Also `for value in lst:`, or `sum(int(value) % y for value in lst)`.